# How to use split array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

```
String data = "12-Jan,TRSF E-BANKING CR 12/01 95031 NABUNG M1 DES  AGUS JENI  ,0,\"50,000.00 CR\",\"3,583,090.00\" ";
System.out.println(data);

output :
12-Jan,TRSF E-BANKING CR 12/01 95031 NABUNG M1 DES  AGUS JENI  ,0,"50,000.00 CR","3,583,090.00"
```

```
String[] items = data.split(",");
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(items));

output :
["12-Jan","TRSF E-BANKING CR 12/01 95031 NABUNG M1 DES  AGUS JENI  ","0","\"50","000.00 CR\"","\"3","583","090.00\""]
```

how to make the comma that is inside the quotes do not split ?

Expected output:

```
["12-Jan","TRSF E-BANKING CR 12/01 95031 NABUNG M1 DES  AGUS JENI","0","50,000.00 CR","3,583,090.00"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [comment by @Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65336932/how-to-use-split-array-in-java#comment115509420_65336932) wisely suggests above, a good [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) parser which can be instructed that double quote is an escape character is probably the best way to go here.  If you're stuck doing this from scratch in Java, [regular expression (regex)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) can be used, with the following pattern:

```regex
".*?"|[^,]+
```

This will attempt to match a double quoted term *first*.  Only if it can't find such a term, then it will consume arbitrarily until hitting the next comma separator (not inside a double quote).  We can use a formal Java regex pattern matcher here:

```java
List<String> terms = new ArrayList<>();
String data = "12-Jan,TRSF E-BANKING CR 12/01 95031 NABUNG M1 DES  AGUS JENI  ,0,\"50,000.00 CR\",\"3,583,090.00\" ";
String pattern = "\".*?\"|[^,]+";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(data.trim());
while (m.find()) {
    terms.add(m.group(0).trim());
}
System.out.println(terms);
```

This prints:

```
[12-Jan, TRSF E-BANKING CR 12/01 95031 NABUNG M1 DES  AGUS JENI, 0,
 "50,000.00 CR", "3,583,090.00"]
```

Comment: I don't really understand about using regex .. but the code you attached works.. thanks great!! :)

Comment: @chaudhary99 I added links to Wikipedia for you to learn more about CSV and regex. You have a choice of CSV parsers, such as [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/csv), with existing Questions & Answers on all of them already on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```java
String data = "12-Jan,TRSF E-BANKING CR 12/01 95031 NABUNG" +
        " M1 DES  AGUS JENI  ,0,\"50,000.00 CR\",\"3,583,090.00\" ";

// any sequence of characters
// between quotes, or a single comma
String pattern = "\".*?\"|,+";

String[] arr1 = data
        // append substrings that matches the given
        // pattern with additional delimiter characters
        .replaceAll(pattern, "$0::::")
        // remove comma
        .replace(",::::", "::::")
        // split into an array
        // by delimiter characters
        .split("::::", 0);

// remove leading and trailing
// whitespaces and empty strings,
// replace sequence of whitespace
// characters with a single whitespace
String[] arr2 = Arrays.stream(arr1)
        .map(String::trim)
        .map(str -> str.replaceAll("\\s+", " "))
        .filter(str -> str.length() > 0)
        .toArray(String[]::new);

// output in a column
Arrays.stream(arr2).forEach(System.out::println);
// 12-Jan
// TRSF E-BANKING CR 12/01 95031 NABUNG M1 DES AGUS JENI
// 0
// "50,000.00 CR"
// "3,583,090.00"
```